# How to scrape data from LocService (http://www.trackdroid.org/locservice.html) using PHP

Tags: php, android, curl, web-scraping

I'm looking to scrape geolocation data from [LocService](http://www.trackdroid.org/locservice.html) (a solution to track GPS pings from an Android phone) and host it in a MySQL database as a PHP cron job. The login system uses HTTPS. I'm having trouble returning anything through cURL.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Gausie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an alternative solution - used a cron job to scrape data from my "Google Latitude Location Badge".